# MongoDB is it possible to runCommand distinct with substr on key

Tags: mongodb, substring, distinct, substr, runcommand

Is it possible to runCommand distinct with substr on the key I'm targeting?
I keep getting `missing : after property id :`

```
db.runCommand(
   {
       distinct: "mycollection",
       key: {"myfield" : { $substr: { "$myfield", 0, 10 } }},
   }
)
```

Comment: Clarity:   You want to get distinct values for `myfield` and *then* do the substring or do the substring first then get the distinct values from that?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I want distinct of the substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do this with `runCommand` `distinct`.   You need to use the agg framework to process the field and then get distinct values using `$group`, thusly:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {$substr: [ "$myfield",0,10]} }}
  ]);
```

Very often it is useful to get the count of those distinct values:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {$substr: ["$myfield",0,10]}, count: {$sum:1} }}
  ]);
```